# MSVC: unrecognizable template declaration/definition (compiles with Clang/GCC)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer

I try to build a library which compiles just fine on OSX (clang) and Linux (GCC/Clang). I stumbled upon a template definition which MSVC/Visual Studio 2017 does not understand. I could boil it down to:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

template<class T>
class Parent {
    class Child {
        friend class Parent;
    public:
        Child(const Child &r);
    };
};

template<class T>
Parent<T>::Child::Child(const Parent<T>::Child &r) {
    *this = r;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    /* code */
    return 0;
}
```

This (still) results in the following error:

```
1>...consoleapplication1.cpp(13): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>...consoleapplication1.cpp(13): error C2059: syntax error: '('
1>...consoleapplication1.cpp(13): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>...consoleapplication1.cpp(13): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

but (still) compiles on OSX with Clang or GCC. `stdafx.h` and also `main` are not part of the actual library code but have been added to allow using this in a VS Windows command line project.

What do I miss here? Does MSVC have issues with member classes or friend declarations in templates?

Comment: [This](https://godbolt.org/g/ZnwTFm) fixes the issue. Looks like one of them is wrong for certain

Comment: @PasserBy: Changing `const Parent<T>::Child` to `const *typename* Parent<T>::Child` indeed solves the issue. Also thank you very much for showing me this extremely useful online compiler. I will definitely use it for arising issues in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VC++'s problem is the fact that the parameter type isn't qualified by `typename`. [[temp.res]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res-7):

> […] within the definition of
>   a member of a class template following the *declarator-id*, the keyword
>   `typename` is not required when referring to the name of a previously
>   declared member of the class template that declares a type or a class
>   template.

The *declarator-id* is the first component of the *declaration*, hence any member type in the parameter clause need not be prefixed by `typename`.

Comment: Just to clarify, non trailing return types does require `typename` because its the _declarator-id_?

Comment: @PasserBy Yeah, and that does make sense, since we parse left-to-right, so we couldn't know better.