# How to solve MSVC treatment of C++ function templates that is different than that of GCC/Clang (unrecognizable template definition)?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

A template helper function exists

```cpp
#include <iostream>

namespace helpers {

  template <typename OUT = float, typename IN>
  OUT normalizeFromRange(IN v, IN min, IN max) {
    return static_cast<OUT>(v - min) / static_cast<OUT>(max - min);
  }

}

int main()
{
    float resultFAuto = helpers::normalizeFromRange<>(10, 0, 40);
    float resultF = helpers::normalizeFromRange<float>(20, 0, 40);
    double resultD = helpers::normalizeFromRange<double>(30, 0, 40);

    std::cout << "resultFAuto: " << resultFAuto << std::endl;
    std::cout << "resultF: " << resultF << std::endl;
    std::cout << "resultD: " << resultD << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

results in

```
resultFAuto: 0.25
resultF: 0.5
resultD: 0.75
```

It compiles on Clang, GCC, which are compilers I use. C++14. 
I want to build the project also on MSVC++ and it [compiles on online MSVC++ compiler](https://rextester.com/UJHN7054) that claims to be using `19.00.23506`

But it fails on my machine that uses `19.16.27027.1`, C++14 set.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 
Version 15.9.9
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.9.9+28307.518
Installed Version: Community
Microsoft Visual C++ 2017
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27027.1
```

with

```
error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
error C2059: syntax error: '('
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

Is the template function defined with incorrect syntax per spec (and GCC, Clang, some MSVC++ version(s) just somehow passes)?
Or is it something MSVC specific, MSVC flags specific, or yet recent MSVC specific?
Something else?
There is [one similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177212/msvc-unrecognizable-template-declaration-definition-compiles-with-clang-gcc), but my knowledge on templates does not allow to see, how it applies here.

Comment: do `min` and `max` happen to be defined as macros somewhere with `MSVC` ? What happens if you rename those parameters?

Comment: Aha, yes. I do get similar errors if I add `#include <windows.h>`, which infamously has `#defines` for `min` and `max`.

Comment: @MFisherKDX `normalizeFromRange(IN v, IN asdassda, IN sdfsfdsf)` and same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your project include `windows.h`?

Including `windows.h` also brings in preprocessor defines for `OUT` and `IN` which I think is causing this error.

Changing the template typenames to `OUTX` and `INX` fixes the errors on my machine.

I found a related SO question: [IN and OUT macros in minwindef.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907493/in-and-out-macros-in-minwindef-h)

Comment: That solved the issue. I do not include any MSW headers, just STL. External libs use do though. Thank you!

Comment: I don't do C++ on MSW normally, only POSIX - GNU and macOS. As I am going to replace the latter with MSW, and thinking of giving MSVC a try (not directly to mingw) as well as MSW headers I feel fun times ahead :)

Comment: @kroko I've been happy with MSVC overall. One suggestion, use the `/permissive-` compiler option for better C++ Standard conformance (Language->Conformance Mode project property page).

Comment: thanks for suggestion, already did (as it is enabled by default in Visual Studio apparently). I'm addicted to warnings, so on GCC I have `-Wall -Wextra` always on and do passes of `-Wconversion -Wpedantic -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic` (clang has `-Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat`)

Comment: @kroko For warnings there is `/W4` (warning level 4). Don't bother with `/Wall` because it causes massive warning message spam with standard library or windows headers.

Comment: Will read upon MSVC specific flags, did not think they "line up in naming" (that MSVC even has `/Wall`). Thanks!